# Show the following limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{1+nx^2}\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{1+nx^2}\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}f(0),$$
where $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $[0,1].$

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Have a look at the solution of Problem 103 http://gaceta.rsme.es/abrir.php?id=860

Comment: Probably you can try to use the identity $$\frac{\pi}{2}f(0)=\lim_{n \to +\infty} f(0)\arctan \sqrt{n} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sqrt{n}\int_0^1 \frac{f(0)}{1+nx^2}dx.$$

Comment: Is $f$ just continuous or also differentiable?

Comment: Just continuous I think. @Dario

Comment: It would be kind of sad to have such an interesting question close, just because the poster didn't state his attempt.

Comment: Sorry I will next time. @YiyuanLee

Answer (score 4):

$$
\sqrt{n}\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{1+nx^2}dx
=\int_0^\sqrt{n} \frac{f(u/\sqrt{n})}{1+u^2} du
= \int_0^\infty f_n(x)dx
$$
Here, $f_n(u) = 1_{u\le \sqrt{n}} 
{f(u/\sqrt{n})}/(1+u^2)\to f(0)/(1+u^2)$ (pointwise convergence) and 
$$\int_0^\infty \sup_n|f_n(x)| dx
\le \sup |f|\int_0^\infty  \frac{du}{1+u^2}<\infty
$$(domination), hence the dominated convergence theorem states:
$$
\sqrt{n}\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{1+nx^2}dx
\to \int_0^\infty f(0)\frac{du}{1+u^2} = \frac{\pi f(0)}{2}
$$

NB: you only need continuity in 0 and boundedness (and measurability!) of $f$ on $[0,1]$ to conclude.

Comment: and why the downvote?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you should add Riemann integrability in your NB.

Comment: you are right :) thanks

Comment: Can I just say that because $f$ is uniformly continuous on the interval, we have $\int_0^{\sqrt{n}}\frac{f(u/\sqrt{n})}{1+u^2} du \rightarrow \int_0^{\infty}f(0)\frac{du}{1+u^2}$?

Comment: what is the theorem you use?

Comment: Splitting it into two limits, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{\sqrt{n}}\frac{f(u/\sqrt{n})}{1+u^2} du =\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{\sqrt{k}}\frac{f(u/\sqrt{n})}{1+u^2} du \rightarrow \int_0^{\infty}f(0)\frac{du}{1+u^2}$ @mookid

Comment: I dont get what you try to do...

Comment: Which part you didn't get?

Comment: I dont get either the first equality or the limit computation.